# IBM Worklight - ANT

Tags: worklight-studio, worklight-server

I have installed

- Eclipse Kepler Edition
- IBM Worklight Studio plugin version 6.1

And now i want to deploy using ANT script as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="target-name">
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
<classpath>
  <pathelement location="WL_INSTALL_DIR/WorklightServer/worklight-ant.jar"/>
</classpath>
</taskdef>
<target name="target-name">
<app-builder
    worklightServerHost="http://server-address:port"
    applicationFolder="adapter-source-files-folder"
    environments="list-of-environments"
    nativeProjectPrefix="project-name"
    outputFolder="output-folder"/>
</target>
</project>
```

But, I can't find **worklight-ant.jar** and also **worklight-ant-deployer.jar**. What software should I install in order to get those file available ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Worklight enterprise edition you can get the `worklight-ant.jar` from server.

If you want to start the Ant task from a computer on which Worklight Server is not installed, you must copy the files `<WorklightInstallDir>/WorklightServer/worklight-ant.jar` and `<WorklightInstallDir>/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar` to your computer.

for more info [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_configure_appserver.html)